# How can I implement slow motion for one player in multiplayer?

Tags: multiplayer, game-mechanics, realtime, time-travel

Special attacks in [Mortal Kombat Mobile](https://m.apkpure.com/mortal-kombat/com.wb.goog.mkx) require slow motion i.e. delay in game play.

On multiplayer mode, when the opponent uses special attacks, I don't observe any lag/delay.

When I use special attack, the game goes in slow motion mode for me, however I guess my opponent doesn't experience any delay.

How is this possible? How can I implement something like this? Can my multiplayer mode still be real-time when using a feature like this?